# How do I remove woocommerce block stylesheets

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Whereas it's straightforward to remove the woocommerce core stylesheets, none of the methods I can find will remove the dozens of block styles that are render-blocking.

with filenames like; `woocommerce/packages/woocommerce-blocks/build/product-title.css` taking between 80ms and 180ms to load, adding up to several seconds.

I have tried using `wp_dequeue_style( 'wc-blocks-style' );` but this has no effect.

I'm not using Gutenberg on this site, let alone in the Woocommerce part so why these overheads are simply piled on to my site is beyond me.

Comment: It looks like something that's happened with woocommerce 8, before that all the blocks styles were in one file and could be dequeued, since 8 there's now 37 extra css files. Lighthouse is screaming at me.